# Error Number: 1137 Can't reopen table: 'd'

Tags: mysql

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_name, location_id
from employees as e, departments as d
where d.department_id = e.department_id and (location_id)
in 
(select location_id
from departments
where department_name = 'Finance')
```

Comment: Not enough info to reproduce, and not reproducible now, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/1B9UGS9i

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join instead of an `IN` clause

```
select employee_id
  , first_name
  , last_name
  , department_name
  , d.location_id
from employees as e
INNER JOIN departments as d ON d.department_id = e.department_id 
INNER JOIN ( select location_id
from departments
where department_name = 'Finance') t  ON t.location_id = d.location_id
```

And for readability you should us explicit `JOIN` syntax, and not implicit syntax based on `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't need subquery to filter location_id

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_name, location_id 
from employees as e join departments as d on d.department_id = e.department_id 
where location_id in (select location_id from departments where department_name = 'Finance')
```

Note: it's better to use explicit join instead of comma separated join

Comment: Thank you so much, but I want to do the same code with sub-query.

Comment: @Fatehin, you can check now - I've edited the answer